# Error when running JS inline in html... I had a prompt('Side name:') and it said it expected ";" after side and name

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<button class="middiv-btn" onclick="THE_CODE">Add an item +</button>
```

The code inside the onclick attribute:

```js
var itemname=prompt('Item Name:');
var node = document.createElement('li');
node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(itemname));
document.querySelector('ul').appendChild(node);
var ol=document.createElement('ol');
var addtop=document.createElement('button');
addtop.onclick='var itemname=prompt('Side Name:');'; 
document.querySelector('ol').appendChild(addtop)
```

This is my code block. The onclick attribute is the problem. I added an attribute to the addtop button element I made. In the onclick attribute, it says I need a semicolon in the string 'Side Name:'

Comment: You are three levels of quotes deep now, but you're still using the single quotes from level two. That's just one reason why inline code is bad practice, the main one being that it creates unreadable, unmaintainable HTML. Move the code to a <script> tag / script instead. Example code: https://jsfiddle.net/gkn5qje1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should not put all your code in the `button` element. Instead put it in a javascript function. You will see it gets a lot clearer now:

```
<script>
function doClick(e){
    var itemname = prompt('Item Name:'); 
    var node = document.createElement('li');
    node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(itemname)); 
    document.querySelector('ul').appendChild(node); 
    //var ol = document.createElement('ol'); // You never use this.
    var addtop = document.createElement('button'); 
    addtop.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Click me!")); // Some text on the button looks better
    addtop.onclick= function(){ // The onclick handler should be a function
        var name = prompt("Side Name:");
        // Not sure why you need this
    }; 
    
    document.querySelector('ol').appendChild(addtop);
}
</script>

<button class="middiv-btn" onclick="doClick(event);">Add an item +</button>
<!-- These are used by your code and should be present.  -->
<ul></ul>
<ol></ol>
```

Comment: I want the ol to be a child of each <li> element with the button inside.

Comment: Oh and I am making a menu service, that is why I need side name and item name.

Comment: So, this is not the right answer to your question?

Comment: Sorry. Indeed, you didn't even ask a question. So, of course, I cannot give an answer. Good luck finding `side name` and `item name` of some kind of `menu service` that nobody ever heard of. Glad to have have solved your initial problem, though.